# Codeigniter 3 password_hash

Tags: php, codeigniter, login

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con **CodeIgniter** y necesito encriptar la password.

*Métodos del Controller: Login.php:*

```
public function index()
{   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('usuario', 'Usuario', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Contraseña', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->input->post('usuario') != '' && $this->input->post('password') != '')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Contraseña', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_verificar_usuario');
    }

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
    {
        $data['titulo'] = 'Login';
        $data['contenido'] = 'login.php';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }
    else {
        redirect(base_url('admin'));
    }
}

public function verificar_usuario() 
{
    $usuario = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('usuario'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

    if($this->Login_model->login($usuario, $password)) 
    {
        redirect(base_url('admin'));
        return true;
    }
    else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('verificar_usuario', 'Los datos son incorrectos.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Métodos del modelo Login_model.php:*

```
public function login($usuario, $password) 
{
    $this->db->select('usuario, password, rol')
             ->from('usuarios')
             ->where('usuario', $usuario)
             ->where('password', $password);

    $result = $this->db->get();

    if($result->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $result->row();

        $data = [
            'usuario'   => $row->usuario,
            'password'  => $row->password,
            'rol'       => $row->rol
        ];

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    else {  
        return false;
    }
}
```

En la base de datos, registré los usuarios mediante el `password_hash()`, y necesito en el login, realizar el `password_verify()` para comparar el password que ingresa el usuario con el de la base de datos. Como logro eso ?

Comment: Hola en mi caso use hash te paso un video con el ejemplo es sencillo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPKpDVWkf7w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En **Métodos del modelo Login_model.php:**

```
public function login($usuario, $password) 
{
    //Realizas una query que solo verifique
    //si existe el usuario
    //Es importante que el nombre de usuario sea único
    $this->db->select('usuario, password, rol')
             ->from('usuarios')
             ->where('usuario', $usuario);

    $result = $this->db->get();

    if($result->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $result->row();

        //Verificas que el password sea correcto
        if(password_verify($password, $row->password))
        {
            $data = [
                'usuario'   => $row->usuario,
                //'password'  => $row->password,
                'rol'       => $row->rol
            ];

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //En este caso la contraseña es incorrecta
            return false;
        }
    }
    else 
    {  
        //En este caso no existe el usuario
        return false;
    }
}
```

Si lo entiendo, esto soluciona tu problema. Pero es importante que en la tabla de usuarios el nombre de usuario sea único.

Saludos

Comment: No hay que modificar el controlador? Lo hice como me lo publicaste, pero no me redirije a la pagina del admin cuando le inserto los datos. Me sigue apareciendo "Datos incorrectos"

Comment: Ahi lo pude solucionar, le habia puesto "TRUE" a los `$this->input->post('usuario')` y esto se ve que me generaba un error. Lo puse para sanitizar los datos pero veo que no hace falta.

Comment: @fedR Perdon, dame 15 min estoy en el trabajo y tengo que salir, regreso

Comment: Tu código funcionó perfectamente!, tuve que corregir lo dicho anterior. Gracias. El usuario en los form validation lo tengo como único, no pueden ingresar otro igual.